# CSS Jquery Hint for slider and overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, hint

I have designed a Slider that works perfectly (As you can see below)

[Pizza slider](http://i57.tinypic.com/14ctpx4.png)

Now I'm gonna a beautiful fancy hint for each item in my slider that pops up with mouse hover and shows some information about the pizza. I created a pilot that works perfect.

[Hint](http://i57.tinypic.com/70yxaw.png)

The problem is since I had to make the slider `overflow: hidden` nothing can go over borders. I read a lot of articles and questions. Apparently the solution most be `overflow-y: hidden` but it doesn't work! Both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` cut off all edges.

What is the best way to hide the wide slider and add popup hint to each item?

Comment: popup should be absolutely positioned and not relative to slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the hint container outside your slider element, and make it absolutely positioned. you can position "hint" via jquery offset() of the clicked element.